# facebook sharer og:url content not displayed after share

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-opengraph

I have set the meta tags as shown in the [example](http://webtrick101.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-configure-facebook-share-fb.html)

Everything works fine, except the og:url tag. Before i hit the share button, it's displaying the correct url as set in the tag. But after I hit the share button, the shared message display the domain name of the site instead. So for example if I set the `og:url` as `www.helloworld.com/hellouniverse`, the shared message `(this can be seen after i hit share)` will instead display `www.helloworld.com`.
Does anyone probably have any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: First check the Facebook debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If that looks good than please post a URL to your site or the HTML source for your tags.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is the default behavior of facebook, they take the domain name from the og:url parameter and display it.

I've tried several approaches to deal with it, but eventually came up with nothing.

Because it is their internal script, there isn't much you can do about it.